# Can :: be used for ipv6 addressing?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, ipv6

IPv6 does not have a network address as `::` and broadcast address as `::FF`. So can they be used for addressing?
Example If if have a ipv6 subnet say `2001:db8::/64`, can `2001:db8::` and `2001:db8::FF` be used as addresses?

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 allows you to use every address in a network as a host address. There are some addresses that are reserved anycast addresses (anycast addresses are unicast host addresses shared by more than one host). For example, the zero address (you should use the special IPv6 Documentation prefix, `2001.db8::/32` for examples) of `2001:db8::/64` is the Subnet-Router anycast address for that network. See [*RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.6.1):

> 2.6.1 Required Anycast Address
>
> The Subnet-Router anycast address is predefined.  Its format is as
> follows:
>
> ```
> |                         n bits                 |   128-n bits   |
> +------------------------------------------------+----------------+
> |                   subnet prefix                | 00000000000000 |
> +------------------------------------------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> The "subnet prefix" in an anycast address is the prefix which
> identifies a specific link. This anycast address is syntactically the
> same as a unicast address for an interface on the link with the
> interface identifier set to zero.
>
> Packets sent to the Subnet-Router anycast address will be delivered to
> one router on the subnet. All routers are required to support the
> Subnet-Router anycast addresses for the subnets which they have
> interfaces.
>
> The subnet-router anycast address is intended to be used for
> applications where a node needs to communicate with one of a set of
> routers on a remote subnet. For example when a mobile host needs to
> communicate with one of the mobile agents on its "home" subnet.

Also, [*RFC 2526, Reserved IPv6 Subnet Anycast Addresses*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2526) reserves the last 128 addresses for anycast addresses:

> 2. Format of Reserved Subnet Anycast Addresses
>
> Within each subnet, the highest 128 interface identifier values are
> reserved for assignment as subnet anycast addresses.
>
> The construction of a reserved subnet anycast address depends on the
> type of IPv6 addresses used within the subnet, as indicated by the
> format prefix in the addresses. In particular, for IPv6 address types
> required to have 64-bit interface identifiers in EUI-64 format, the
> universal/local bit MUST be set to 0 (local) in all reserved subnet
> anycast addresses, to indicate that the interface identifier in the
> address is not globally unique. IPv6 addresses of this type are
> currently specified to be those having format prefixes 001 through
> 111, except for Multicast Addresses (1111 1111) [3].
>
> Specifically, for IPv6 address types required to have to have 64-bit
> interface identifiers in EUI-64 format, these reserved subnet anycast
> addresses are constructed as follows:
>
> ```
> |              64 bits            |      57 bits     |   7 bits   |
> +---------------------------------+------------------+------------+
> |           subnet prefix         | 1111110111...111 | anycast ID |
> +---------------------------------+------------------+------------+
>                                   |   interface identifier field  |
> ```
>
> For other IPv6 address types (that is, with format prefixes other than
> those listed above), the interface identifier is not in EUI-64 format
> and may be other than 64 bits in length; these reserved subnet anycast
> addresses for such address types are constructed as follows:
>
> ```
> |              n bits             |    121-n bits    |   7 bits   |
> +---------------------------------+------------------+------------+
> |           subnet prefix         | 1111111...111111 | anycast ID |
> +---------------------------------+------------------+------------+
>                                   |   interface identifier field  |
> ```
>
> The subnet prefix here consists of all fields of the IPv6 address
> except the interface identifier field.  The interface identifier field
> in these reserved subnet anycast addresses is formed from a 7-bit
> anycast identifier ("anycast ID"), with the remaining (highest order)
> bits filled with all one's; however, for interface identifiers in
> EUI-64 format, the universal/local bit in the interface identifier
> MUST be set to 0. The anycast identifier identifies a particular
> reserved anycast address within the subnet prefix, from the set of
> reserved subnet anycast addresses.
>
> The motivation for reserving the highest addresses from each subnet
> rather than the lowest addresses, is to avoid conflicting with some
> existing official and unofficial uses of the low-numbered addresses in
> a subnet. For example, these low-numbered addresses are often used for
> the ends of a point-to-point link, for tunnel endpoints, for manually
> configured unicast addresses when a hardware token is not available
> for the network interface, and even for manually configured static
> addresses for the routers on a link. Reserving only 128 values for
> anycast identifiers (rather than perhaps 256) means that the minimum
> possible size of interface identifiers in an IPv6 address is 8 bits
> (including room in the subnet for unicast addresses as well as
> reserved subnet anycast addresses), allowing the division between
> subnet prefix and interface identifier in this case to be
> byte-aligned.
>
> As with all IPv6 anycast addresses [3], these reserved subnet anycast
> addresses are allocated from the IPv6 unicast address space.  All
> reserved subnet anycast addresses as defined in this document are
> reserved on all links, with all subnet prefixes. They MUST NOT be used
> for unicast addresses assigned to any interface.

Although only one of the addresses is currently defined for use:

> 3. List of Reserved Subnet Anycast Addresses
>
> Currently, the following anycast identifiers for these reserved subnet
> anycast addresses are defined:
>
> ```
>  Decimal   Hexadecimal     Description
>  -------   -----------     -----------
>   127         7F           Reserved
>   126         7E           Mobile IPv6 Home-Agents anycast [4]
>   0-125       00-7D        Reserved
> ```
>
> Additional anycast identifiers are expected to be defined in the
> future.